# Inializing third-party library within durandal lifecycle callbacks

Tags: javascript, durandal

I need to initialize third party library - videojs - every time the viewmodel activates. However, the problem is library requires a dom element, which is not attached yet when durandal's activate callback is being executed.

```
//viewmodel
define (["jquery", "knockout", "videojs"], function ($, ko, videojs) {
  var

    activate = function (videoSource) { //route param
      var videoTag = $('#video').get(0); //undefined
      var playerInstance = new videojs.Player(videoTag); //error

      playerInstance.src(videoSource); //loads video from route parameter
      playerInstance.play(); //starts to play
    };

    return {
      activate: activate
    }
});

//view
<section id="page-quiz-answer" class="page">
    <video id="video"></video>
</section>
```

Comment: Consider using either `attached` or `compositonComplete`. See  http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks for details.

Comment: @RainerAtSpirit, I did, but those callbacks are only called once, whereas I need the code to execute on every activation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM is not yet available in the #activate callback.  You would need to access the DOM element in the #attached or #compositionComplete callback.  You can read [here](http://aljs.com/documentation/Interacting-with-the-DOM.html) about the signatures of those callbacks, along with their intended purposes.

```
//viewmodel
define (["jquery", "knockout", "videojs"], function ($, ko, videojs) {
    var attached = function (view) { //route param
      var $view = $(view);
      var $videoTag = $view.find('#video'); //undefined
      var playerInstance = new videojs.Player($videoTag); //error

      playerInstance.src(videoSource); //loads video from route parameter
      playerInstance.play(); //starts to play
    };

    return {
      attached: attached
    }
});
```

**ANOTHER APPROACH**

You could also write a custom Knockout binding and encapsulate the logic of accessing the DOM element there.

I would actually suggest this approach as I'm suspicious of the point where you pass in a DOM reference to `videojs.Player()`.  This screams for encapsulation in a custom binding.

**[EDIT]**

**EXAMPLE OF USAGE OF CUSTOM BINDING**

Consider this usage in the view:

```
<div id='video' data-bind=player: {instance: playerInstance, source: videoSource}></div>
```

With this, you can then move all of the logic in the #attached function above into the custom binding.  If you need to dynamically control the playerInstance, you can create an object literal with observable properties in your viewmodel, something like this:

```
var playerOptions = {
        action: ko.observable('play'),
        player: new videojs.Player(),
        source: ko.observable(videoSource)
    };
```

and change the binding to this:

```
<div id='video' data-bind=player: {options: playerOptions}></div>
```

Your custom binding would look something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.player = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor),
            $element = $(element);            

        var playerInstance = options.player;
        playerInstance.source = options.source();
        playerInstance.do(options.action());
    }
};
```

I'm not sure how your Player is connected to the DOM.  I can see only that you're passing in a DOM element.  But inside this binding, you have access to the element itself.

Comment: Both callbacks fire only once during the initial load of application. They don't get called after further activations. I also considered to use custom binding, however I am not quite sure how to obtain `playerInstance` in the viewmodel in such case.

Comment: @Dziamid I edited my answer to give you an idea how to proceed.  I would have to see Player to fully develop a custom binding.  But I think you can get the meaning from my answer.  With the custom binding approach, you now have a completely reusable player.  In any case, I would try to avoid this pattern: `new Player(DOMElement)`.  That just goes against the Durandal grain.

Comment: I love your solution, but the problem is you cannot create player instance without a dom element (`new videojs.Player()` throws error).

Comment: Thanks! And, yes, I would need to see the full of Player.  It may be that you _have_ to pass in a DOM element.

Comment: Well, I completely adapted the custom binding solution. I turns out there's no real need to have the reference to player instance in viewmodel in my case, hence no problem with callbacks. Thank you again.